# Post Type => Any conundrum

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-type

I have a number of regular posts and pages in a regular category called "Featured". I have also installed a plugin called "Event Organizer" that creates its own custom post type called "Event" and has its own interface for creating plugin-specific categories.

Anyways, what I've created is a basic highlight slider using a query to pull in the featured category posts and pages (I enabled categories in my pages) as well as the event posts. This is the query:

```
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'any',
  'showposts' => $featured_num,
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'featured'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'event-category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'featured-event',
    )
    )
  );
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The problem is that everything works fine on my local testing environment but absolutely refuses to work on my web host. In my local testing environment both the "featured" posts and pages are pulled up *AS WELL AS* the event custom posts. On my web host only the event posts show. If I switch "post type" to `array('post','page')` I get the **featured** posts and pages but lose the event posts.

Comment: have you tried `array( 'post', 'page', 'event' )`? look at the query on both setups to see if there are differences- add `print_r( $my_query )` and inspect the SQL generated in both cases.

Comment: Add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) please.

Answer (score 1):

These scenarios become much easier if you use plugins like [posts2posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) to establish a relation (for example featured posts to this page) and then pull them easily in the context

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
'post_status' => array('featured','publish')
```

and

```
'post_type' => array('post','page','event')
```

but if Event post type slug is 'event'

Also it's a known issue that `'post_type' => 'any'` doesn't work!

Comment: I'm looking at [/wp-includes/query.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L0) at lines 2897-2902 and see that it does indeed officially support using the "any" post_type; if supplied, it enumerates through known post types using `get_post_types()` and would potentially fail if it couldn't find any (hence the `AND 1=0` SQL it injects).  This said, I've never tried this and didn't even believe this was possible using standard WP queries.